# vlookup search entire text string to match the lookup word

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, vlookup

I am trying to lookup a keyword within a text string and numbers within a cell and from the list of cells.

Currently, my formula will correctly pull the right item from the list as long as the lookup value (text) entered lies within the first word of one of the text strings.

The problem is that sometimes it's difficult to recall what exactly the first word in a title is and so would like to be able to search the entire text string for a match.

I am apply the following formula with wild card like below

F3 `=VLOOKUP("*"&$E3&"*"&F$2,CHOOSE({1,2},$B$3:$B$19&$A$3:$A$19,$C$3:$C$19),2,0)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmpkE.png)

Comment: I tried copy and past the data,  but its appearing unevenly. Can you please explain me how to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula would work

```
=VLOOKUP($E3&F$2,CHOOSE({1,2},$B$3:$B$19&$A$3:$A$19,$C$3:$C$19),2,0)
```

However, in your example, E3 & F2 would make : **STEELPOWER LH 123**

And there is no match for this

You would need F2 before the E3 etc.

```
=VLOOKUP(F$2&$E3&"*",CHOOSE({1,2},$B$3:$B$19&$A$3:$A$19,$C$3:$C$19),2,0)
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. There is no another way because I have huge data. I can't change the each entry. I saw the similar post in  stackoverflow. The formula lookup(2,15) search something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The following would also work:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&$E3&"*",INDEX(FILTER($A$3:$C$19,$A$3:$A$19=F$2),SEQUENCE(5,1),{2,3}),2,FALSE),"")
```

Paste that in cell F3, the copy the cell and paste to the entire output table.

It uses `FILTER()` to find all the records whose `ID column` (column A in your pic) matches the column header (hence "F$2", not "$F$2") in the output table. That is three columns of material (it will be an array Excel uses internally so it doesn't need more real estate than the single cell in the output table) but arranged unfortunately for `VLOOKUP()` so the column order is rearranged by `INDEX()` (the `{2,3}` part:  one could include all three columns but just the two are needed so the internal array will be smaller this way, hence faster and also able to use more rows in the table before erroring due to exceeding the capacity for material in a formula's calculation).

`INDEX()` would just as happily do {3,1,2} or {3,2} or... well, any arrangement, including putting a column in more than once. Just a "by the way" for other work.

So now the collumns are in the right order for the `VLOOKUP()`, but how to do a search for a substring that could be anywhere, or nowhere? Use the `*` wildcard and the cell containing the substring. That is the `"*"&E3&"*"` portion. It does the lookup in the TWO columns you are using and the value needed is in column two even though the data itself has three columns.

Finally, to blank out cells with errors `IFERROR()` gives them "" entries. If you desire the exact picture with the errors, just remove that wrap from the formula.

Bear in mind, if you have 10,000 rows of this material and what you are looking up  would yield 943 rows, only the first instance is going to be found. But you seem OK with that as it is not mentioned so I did not worry about it.

This uses `SEQUENCE()` which did not exist in 2017. There was an older technique for generating such sequences that is easy to find on any Excel help site.

Also, if interested, one could copy out the `FILTER()` portion of the formula, wrap it with a `COUNTA()` function, and use that to replace the "5" in the `SEQUENCE()` function so that the number of rows returned to the internal array Excel will use in the formula would be dynamic rather than hardcoded. Or one could have a cell somewhere with a `COUNTA()` function simply counting the original rows in the data that match each column header rather than using the `FILTER()` portion. The advantage of the former is that there will never be a mismatch, period. The advantage of the latter is that the former adds a complicated chunk of formula in place of just a single digit while the latter would add just a cell reference so the latter might be much easier to many to maintain and improve over time.